# Template user defined conversions to abstract class reference and the Intel compiler

Tags: c++, icc

I have the following (very simplified) "container" class:

```
class container
{
    public:

        template<typename T> container(const boost::shared_ptr<T> &rhs)
            : m_content(rhs) { }

        template<typename T>
        operator T const & () const
        {
            return get<T>();
        }

        template<typename T>
        T const & get() const
        {
            return *boost::any_cast< boost::shared_ptr<T> >(m_content);
        }

    private:
        boost::any m_content;
};
```

It should store objects in the `boost::any` container in the form of a shared pointer. If I store some object, say, of the `boost::shared_ptr<some_type>` type in the container, I would like to get the reference (`const some_type&`) simply by a user-defined conversion which would allow to do something like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<some_type> x(new some_type);
container cx = x;

...

// user-defined conversion
const some_type &y = cx;

// a template conversion using a "getter"
const some_type &y = cx.get<some_type>();
```

Sometimes, I need to store objects derived from some abstract type and do the same sort of type conversion to the reference of this abstract type, for example, like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<some_abstract_type> x(new some_derived_type);
container cx = x;

...

// user-defined conversion
const some_abstract_type &y = cx;

// a template conversion using a "getter"
const some_abstract_type &y = cx.get<some_abstract_type>();
```

Both the user-defined conversion and the template "getter" work fine with GCC. However, the Intel C++ compiler seems to have a problem with the (user-defined) conversion while the "getter" works.

For example, the following code works with GCC but not with Intel:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class container
{
    public:

        template<typename T> container(const boost::shared_ptr<T> &rhs)
            : m_content(rhs) { }

        template<typename T>
        operator T const & () const
        {
            return get<T>();
        }

        template<typename T>
        T const & get() const
        {
            return *boost::any_cast< boost::shared_ptr<T> >(m_content);
        }

    private:
        boost::any m_content;
};

class base
{
    public:
        virtual ~base() { }
        virtual void f() const = 0;
};

class derived : public base
{
    public:
        virtual ~derived() { }
        virtual void f() const { std::cout << "hello\n"; }
};

void foo(const container &c)
{
    const base & a = c;
    a.f();
}

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<base> a(new derived);
    container c = a;
    foo(c);
}
```

With Intel, I get this error:

```
test.cpp(44): error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "const container" to "const base" exists
      const base & a = c;
                       ^

compilation aborted for test.cpp (code 2)
```

On the other hand, if I replace `base` with `derived` in both `main()` and `foo()` (or use the "getter" instead of the type conversion in `foo()`), everything works fine with Intel too. Is it possible to convince the Intel compiler to use the user-defined type conversion to the reference type when `T` is an abstract class?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

---

**EDIT:** Interestingly, using the type conversion to the pointer type works fine. If I add

```
template<typename T>
operator T const * () const
{
    return &get<T>();
}
```

to the `container` class and replace `foo()` with

```
void foo(const container &c)
{
    const base * a = c;
    a->f();
}
```

then it works also with Intel.

Comment: I am confused as to the reasoning for `**boost::any_cast< boost::shared_ptr<T> >(&m_content)` over `*boost::any_cast< boost::shared_ptr<T> >(m_content)` (or why `m_content` is not just a `boost::shared_ptr<T> >` to begin with, but I'm guessing the loss of the reason for that is due to your simplification); going by the source, `any_cast` does appear to support pass-by-reference for `any` objects (see [boost.any.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/any.hpp)).

Comment: @JAB There are actually two variants of `any_cast`, one which takes a (const/non-const) reference to `any` and returns `T` (so creates a temporary), and one which takes a pointer to `any` and returns a pointer to `T` (which subsequently can be used to return a reference to `T` from a function because it does not create a temporary instance of `T`).

Comment: In the cases you refer to, `T` is technically `shared_ptr<T>`, and as you're immediately dereferencing the shared pointer anyway there's no reason you need to create that additional pointer aside from trying to save a tiny bit of space/CPU cycles. (Most compilers would just elide the copy anyway as the `shared_ptr<T>` would indeed be a temporary used in that one location, would they not? Unless you've found that the compilers you use do not perform elision in that case, using the pointer form seems like an unnecessary preemptive optimization.)

Comment: Fooling around on http://gcc.godbolt.org reveals that ICC [will perform](http://goo.gl/E02WFr) the conversion for a non-const ref. Sacrifice a little const-correctness and and you might have a viable workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that it is a bug in the Intel C++ compiler and was filed in the bug tracking list.

Answer (score 1):

I would return a pointer in the getter:

```
template<typename T>
T const * get() const {
    return boost::any_cast< boost::shared_ptr<T> >(m_content);
}
```

This avoids the conversion problem, and does not crash immediately if you pass a null pointer to your container.

Example:

```
void foo(const container &c)
{
    const base* a = c.get<base>();
    a->f();
}
```

You could also add a function `valid()` which checks if there is something in the container:

```
bool valid() const {
    return m_content != NULL;
}
```

**Edit:** Your addition to your question follows exactly in this direction.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's why I mentioned that the class is "very simplified" :-) What I do not understand here, however, and that is the (possibly somewhat hidden) point of my question, why the Intel compiler does not "see" the user defined type conversion to the reference type when `T` is an abstract type while this is not the case for the conversion to the pointer type (abstract/non-abstract). As I would like to avoid any kind of non-standard constructs, the question probably is whether I'm doing something wrong or there is a bug in the Intel compiler.

Comment: I do not see an error in you code. However, sometimes standard conforming constructs are just not supported by every compiler...